# fill a matrix by row in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to run a loop and fill a matrix. Here is a sample data:

```
#generate sample data
reg<-rep(c("a","b","c","d"),each=3)
year<-rep(c(2005:2008),each=3)
sea<-rep(c("Winter","Summer","Autumn"),4)
set.seed(1)
area<-runif(12)
prod<-runif(12)
yld<-runif(12)
dat<-data.frame(reg,year,sea,area,prod,yld)
dat$reg<-as.character(dat$reg)
dat$sea<-as.character(dat$sea)
str(dat)

#create an empty matrix to store my results
results.mat <- matrix(0, ncol = 6, nrow = NROW(unique(dat$reg)))

#create a loop
for (j in unique(sort(dat$reg))){
reg<-dat[dat$reg==j,]
for (k in unique(sort(reg$year))){
  year<-reg[reg$year==k,]
  results.mat<-year[year$area==max(year$area),]
}}
results.mat
```

What I am trying to do is for each `reg` and for each `year`, I want to extract that row where `area` is maximum. This implies for `a`, row with `Autumn` should be selected since `area` is maximum among all the three values of `area`. Similarly, for `b`, row with `Winter` should be selected since `area` is the maximum. Similarly, for `d`, row with `Summer` should be selected since `area` is maximum.

Therefore the final matrix (or dataframe) should have one row for `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`. However when I run my above loop, it only gives me the row for `d` and not for the other three. I think this has to do with the last line of loop where I specify it fill the matrix `results.mat` and it overwrites the previous selection. But I am not sure for matrix, how should I fill rows by rows.

Thanks

Comment: Matrices and data.frames are different. If you want to select rows of a data.frame, the result will/should also be a data.frame (as in the answer below).

Comment: One option in base R: `dat[as.logical(ave(dat$area,dat$reg,dat$year,FUN=function(x) x==max(x),drop=TRUE)),]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using the `data.table` package is as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

# subset data according to max area by reg-year
dat[, .SD[which.max(area),], by=c("reg", "year")]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `result.mat` as you described is what you want, there is a more systematic way of doing it by using some data manipulation package such as `dplyr`, which allows you to manipulate data based on groups and filter rows which satisfy some conditions. In `dplyr` package, you can achieve the `result.mat` in the following way.

```
library(dplyr);
dat %>% group_by(reg, year) %>% filter(area == max(area))

Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
Groups: reg, year [4]

    reg  year    sea      area      prod        yld
  (chr) (int)  (chr)     (dbl)     (dbl)      (dbl)
1     a  2005 Autumn 0.5728534 0.7698414 0.01339033
2     b  2006 Winter 0.9082078 0.4976992 0.38238796
3     c  2007 Winter 0.9446753 0.3800352 0.48208012
4     d  2008 Summer 0.2059746 0.6516738 0.82737332
```

Comment: Another standard option is `%>% slice(which.max(area))` instead of `filter`.